# Input string was not in a correct format when parse in multithreading

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Does Anybody can explain this:
[image: Screen]

How does it possible to throw exception when parsing "55.01"? I use multithreading.

--edit--
but... sometimes it works
[image]

This realy make me sad ;(
i use .NET 4.0 and VS2010.

--edit 2---

Ok, I made a little progress. When I do not use multithreading everything works perfect. But when I use multithreading (probably)one of a thread throw FormatException in place which is shown in the picture.

Comment: Exactly which string *doesn't parse*? Is it only *one*? Can you come up with a simplified works/fails case *not* involving `words`?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible the system is set for some culture that expects a comma as the decimal point.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx:

> The s parameter is interpreted using the formatting information in a NumberFormatInfo object that is initialized for the current thread culture. For more information, see CurrentInfo. To parse a string using the formatting information of some other culture, call the Double.Parse(String, IFormatProvider) or Double.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider) method.